# Override all CSS styles for block

Tags: html, css, iframe, overriding

I'm using HTML examples on my website (using Crayon) and want to show output as well.

But I want the output to show as pure as it would have without any of my website's own stylesheets.

I can of course do this with an iframe, but that seems tedious. Is there perhaps another trick or library that anyone is aware of?

Thanks

Comment: please you can post your source code or fiddle?

Comment: I don't have an example unfortunately. It's really more a conceptual question about showing unstyled content within a page of styled content.
Perhaps an iframe is the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this. Works well...

```
$('.crayon-title').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).parent().siblings('.crayon-plain-wrap').children('textarea').text();
    var x=window.open();
    x.document.open();
    x.document.write(content);
    x.document.close();
})
```